# Невозможность установки OS и открытия биос

Tags: linux, ос, bios, hdd, uefi

Имею старенький ноут с Ubuntu и Windows 10. Десятка сильно тормозит - использую линукс. Его я ставил как вторую систему и дал всего 30гб. Сейчас захотел снести все системы и заного поставить только линукс. Вроде все нормально установилось, но после нескольких запусков система стала загружаться черным экраном и мигающим курсором. ВООБЩЕ никакие манипуляции с grub-ом не помогли. Изменение параметров входа тоже. Но когда я не смог зайти в биос (UEFI) я конкретно при**ел. Ни выбор устройства загрузки, ни настройки. То-есть я никак не мог зайти с флешки. Я вынимал батарейку - биос не перезагружался. Я решил снять HDD и тогда, когда в ноуте небыло никаких насителей, кроме флешки, открылось, что бы я мог подумать.... Меню выбора boot. Только так. Раньше он не мог открыться (F12) и смог только сейчас. Но когда начал устанавливать систему диск HDD, который я подключил после он, естевствнно не видел диск. Тогда я подключил диск ко 2му ПК и уже там его отфармотировал. У меня получилось загрузится с флешки и установить линукс. Но при входе черный экран и невозможность входа в биос повторились. Я опять отфармотировал диск с второго ПК и ставил уже Windows 7. Но он не хотел ставить систему из-за какой-то ошибки несовместимости с диском и просил проверить настройки биоса, но туда я зайти не мог. Это был замкнутый круг ада, на который я потратил 2 дня. Но до этого я же смог установить сюда винду и линукс???? Почему тогда сейчас не работает.

P.S. разные версии OS я пробовал

Моё предположение - что-то с HDD, но на втором ПК он спокойно работает как флешка.

Устройство - Lenovo IdeaPad Z585

Comment: я бы посоветовал подключить `usb клавиатуру` и при включении хаотично тыкать на все кнопки типа `f2` или `del`. Именно переберать. `BIOS` должен открытся независиммо от устройст установленных в ноутбук.

Comment: Все равно не работает.

Comment: Очень странная ситуация. Когда включаете ноутбук - появдяется заставка `BIOS`? Может лого производителя?. Наверное будет правльным откинуть `АКБ`, снять батарейку и оставте его так на ночь. За ночь параметры сбросятся, и должно как минимум появится лого `BIOS` в котором будет указанна клавища для входа в него.

Comment: Максим, да лого появляестя вместе с подсказкой для клавиш.